# How to make use of an ID in meteor iron router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I know that I can put :id in the path of my route so that I get a specific URL. Thats what I can get form tutorials I found online. But how can I make use of this feature? What is the benefit?
I assume that the ID is passed internally as like an url parameter, since in the data function seems to be specific return, based on an ID. But I am not sure.

```
this.route('projectView',{
    path:'/projects/:id',
    layoutTemplate:'mainLayout',
    loginRequired:'entrySignIn',
    waitOn:function(){
        Meteor.subscribe('customers');
        return Meteor.subscribe('projects');
    },
    data:function(){
        Session.set('active_project',this.params.id);
        return Projects.findOne({_id:this.params.id});
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `path` looks like `/projects/:id`. Under the hood, the router converts the contents of `:id` into `this.params.id` which is what you are using in your `data` hook.

In other words, if the path `/projects/abc123` was encountered by the router, it would know that it should use the `projectView` route and `this.params.id` should equal `abc123` when loading the corresponding data.